# C# WPF ListView add icon near item

Tags: c#, wpf

How add near item in listview on left side small icon?

WPF Code:

```
<ListView Name="listView1" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="501" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Add item to listview

```
foreach (var item in found)
{
     MainWindow.mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
     {
         listView1.Items.Add(item);
     }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to amend the `DataTemplate` as shown below.

**POCO List View Item** *(Data Model)*:

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var listItemObj = myListView.Items.Add(new MyListItem {Icon = "Default Icon", Text = "Default Text"});
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
       <ListView Name="myListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Padding="5 0 0 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Result:**

[image]